# Risks for health from non food grade stainless steel false bottom

Tags: biab, stainless

My set up is for electric BIAB (brew in a bag) so I use a false bottom.  The problem is that I don't know if the stainless steel I use is food grade or not.  Are there any great risks for my health? Should I replace it or not?

Comment: Which grade of stainless steel is it? 304, 316 etc..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never heard of non-food-grade stainless steel. Some are more or less susceptible to corrosion than others, but as far as I know all stainless steels are food grade.

> [...] stainless steel is a safe option when it
>   comes to use with food and beverage, as there are no chemicals that
>   can migrate into your food from these products.

From http://mightynest.com/blog/stainless-steel-all-about-food-grade-304-188-and-1810